# Error: Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable, replace with let

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My function is set like this

```
handleCheckoutButtonClick = () => {
    const {bottlesChoice, secondChoice, thirdChoice} = this.state;
    const {block} = this.props;
    const membershipClubUrl = '';

    if (bottlesChoice === '4' && secondChoice == 'yes' && thirdChoice == 'yes') {
        membershipClubUrl = block.pbMembershipsJoinClubs[0].clubUrl;
    } else if(bottlesChoice === '4' && secondChoice === 'yes' && thirdChoice === 'no') {
        membershipClubUrl = block.pbMembershipsJoinClubs[1].clubUrl;
    } else if(bottlesChoice === '4' && secondChoice === 'no' && thirdChoice === 'no') {
        membershipClubUrl = block.pbMembershipsJoinClubs[2].clubUrl;
    } else {
        membershipClubUrl = block.pbMembershipsJoinClubs[3].clubUrl;
    }
}
```

When I set membershipClubUrl with a const, I get the error above from my IDE(PHPStorm). But when I set it to let like it suggests, I get "Remove unused assignment". What's the correct way of setting membershipClubUrl here

Comment: "Remove unused assignment" seems like a linter warning whereas the other is a true error. Using `let` is correct if you need to reassign it later on. The warning is just telling you that you've created a variable that doesn't get used.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks! But it's getting used in my if statement right, or no?

Comment: You used it in if - else statement but after that it's not used again. That's why PHPStorm shows notice. Replace `const` with `let` and use `membershipClubUrl` after if-else statement.(return it or like that)

Comment: `const membershipClubUrl = '';` <-- saying `membershipClubUrl` is not supposed to update.... but you update it. That is how `const` works. If the value changes, you have to use `let`

Comment: @bravemaster got it, thank you!